Possibly mistake in Silverman for the equation of a twist of an elliptic curve when $j=0$
In Silverman X.5.4, he gave the equation of a twist for different $j$.
But when I compute $j=0$, I got something slightly different, whereas I think I really just imitate the case $j=1728$.
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a field $K$ given by the equation $y^2=x^3+B$. Assume the absolute Galois group of $K$ is $G$. Take any $D\in K^\times$ to twist the curve.
According to Silverman, the automorphism given by $\zeta$ acts as $(\zeta^2x,\zeta^3y)$.
Then $X:=x/\sqrt[6]{D^2}$ and $Y:=y/\sqrt[6]{D^3}$ are fixed by $G$. Assume the original equation is $y^2=x^3+B$. Then the new equation is $DY^2=DX^3+B$ which is $Y^2=X^3+D^{-1}B$.
It seems that the twist class correspond to $D\in K^\times/(K^\times)^6$ is this class $Y^2=X^3+D^{-1}B$ not $Y^2=X^3+DB$.
This two classes are in general different classes. Via his construction, the natural one should be the one I computed? But on the the other hand, this two classes are just inverse to each other. So it seems not that "wrong". I wonder does this matter at all?
It could be also I made mistake during coordinate transformation, but I checked several times.

Edit: Indeed, it is really just a matter of choice of the isomorphism between $\mu_n\to\mathrm{Aut}(E)$. First, Silverman gave this isomorphism $(\zeta^2x,\zeta^3y)$ in some chapter before. But then in the proof of $j=1728$, he used $(\zeta^2x,\zeta y)$. Then he got his desired equation. If we use the very first isomorphism, we will get a minus one as well.

You should explain all notation like $\zeta,D,G,K$ etc. - there could be people who know this subject well, and would be able to help you, but don't have a copy of Silverman in front of them. It also helps future readers who don't know the subject so well and would struggle to guess

The substitution $(X,Y) = ((\sqrt[6]{D})^{-4}X',D^{-1}Y')$ applied to $Y^2 = X^3 + D^{-1}B$ gives the desired equation.

This is not true because this morphism is defined over $\overline K$ not over $K$. Twists in different classes should exists no morphism over $K$. In general, $c$ and $c^{-1}$ are different classes in $K^\times/(K^\times)^4$.

@CO2 aren't twists defined over $\overline{K}$ by definition? And after composing this map with your original automorphism it is still in the same extension.

My point was to see whether these two classes are the same in the set of twist classes, i.e., need to check over $K$. They are all isomorphic over $\overline K$ as they all have the same $j$-invariant.

Then it should just be up to the choice of the sixth roots of unity of $D$, and the two twists represent the same $D \in K^{\times}/K^{\times 6} \cong Twist((E,O)/K)$

But sixth root of $D$ need not be in $K$. Take $K=\mathbb Q$ and $D=2$.
